# Filtering 2 lists in a performant way

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists:

`newUpdates` and `updatesToAdd`

I first of all need to remove all the occurrences of `updatesToAdd` from the `newUpdates` list by their Id. Then I need to add all `updatesToAdd` back into `newUpdates` to prevent duplicates.

It may not be clear why I'm doing this, but I need to swap out multiple occurrences of items that share the same Id (different update type) to then reinsert just one item for that Id with a main/master/catch all update type.

The code I have so far does this, but it runs very slowly. Is there a more performant way to write this?

```
    var newUpdates = new List<Entity>();
    var updatesToAdd = new List<Entity>();

    var Ids = updatesToAdd.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
    newUpdates.RemoveAll(x => Ids.Contains(x.Id));
    newUpdates.AddRange(updatesToAdd);
```

I tried doing:

```
    newUpdates.Union(updatesToAdd).ToList();
```

However, I still ended up with duplicates in my list.

Comment: Use a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) for `Ids`. Solves both your performance and duplicates issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Except instead?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2

or Contains is false.

In fact I think you have a bug. I think you want to do this:

```
var newUpdates = new List<Entity>(); //overall list to add
var updatesToAdd = new List<Entity>();  //later list to add

var Ids = updatesToAdd.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();  //this line chagned
newUpdates.RemoveAll(x => Ids.Contains(x.Id));
newUpdates.AddRange(updatesToAdd);
```